# Spark make-distribution with Hadoop 3.1.2

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Attempting to build Spark 2.4.3 from source with current Hadoop 3.1.2 (on CentOS 7.5):

```
./dev/make-distribution.sh --name hadoop3.1.2 --pip --tgz -Phadoop-3.1
```

produces a tarball with Hadoop 3.1.0 jars, but

```
./dev/make-distribution.sh --name hadoop3.1.2 --pip --tgz -Phadoop-3.1.2
```

results in a build against Hadoop 2.6.5.

`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=hadoop.version -Phadoop-3.1.2` seems to indicate that 3.1.2 is not a valid tag, but it is the current stable release of Hadoop, and its a tag in Maven Central.

Is there a dependency that is unmet preventing the `make-distribution` script from finding what it needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned the profiles are defined in the pom file of the Spark source. Highest Hadoop version is 3.1.0.